# Javascript : go back with new parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, back

I have a problem with the `history.back()` function.

I have three page A,B,C:

- the first one (A) has a link to the second (B) and the link contains
  parameters (?id=..).
- B has a link to C
- I go back from C to B with `history.back()`.

The problem is that `back()` function use in fact the A to B link (from the history) that contains the parameters but I need to change these.

So I changed `history.back()` to a simple href but of course, now if I click on back, I go back to C page (what I don't want).

So is there a solution to use `back()` with different parameters? (I use Angular, may be something can help).

A.html :

```
<body ng-controller="AuthentCtrl">
    <div align="center">
        <button ng-click="location.href = 'view/listing.html?id=' + id + '&first=' + newAuthent;">Go!</button>
        <br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

B.html

```
<body onload="init()">
<script>
    function init(){
        var params = location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        id = params[0].split('=')[1];
        var firstCo = params[1].split('=')[1];
        // execute some code, function of parameters
    }
</script>
</body>
```

C.html

```
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <button ng-click="history.back()">Go!</button>
        <br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you create a Plunkr or a fiddle for this issue? I wish to know exactly how you are using the `back()` functionality.

Comment: I'm gonna update my post with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to alter your history with javascript.

Have you tried using the [referrer](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp) property to figure out on Page "B", if you're coming from page "A" or "C"?

Comment: Yes and in both case it's the URL I use in the href of A button. Thanks for your answer, I'll find something else!